# VSCode Terraform login API Token not pastable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-cloud

Reproduction Steps:

1. In VSCode, install git and run 'terraform login'
2. In the question 'Do you still want to proceed' --->Type 'yes'
3. It will take you to terraform cloud
4. Copy and try to paste the auth token from Terraform cloud in your VSCode terminal as per the following screenshot.
   [image]

How can I login to terraform cloud from the terminal?

1. I have tried Ctrl+shift+v
2. Ctrl+v
3. I basically want to use terraform login command to login to tfc via terminal

Comment: Is it possible that the key is being pasted, but the value isn't echoed on the terminal? Have you tried hitting Enter after pasting?

Comment: What about right mouse button click?

Answer (score 0):

To login into `Terraform Cloud` via the terminal, use the `terraform login` command, which you are already using. This will request you for your credentials and generate an API token for authorization.

To paste the token/password into the terminal, enter`ctrl` + `shift` +`v` ; `shift` + `Insert`; or simply right click, a `paste` option will pop up to insert it.

*Run* `terraform login` *and it prompts us to generate token as below:*

[image]

*Redirected to the browser on which the token has generated:*

[image]

*I dragged the cursor to the relevant console and pasted the generated token using the right-click mouse option. It successfully logged in.*

[image]

Refer [github issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/25923).

You can also [check](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961175/copy-and-paste-doesnt-work-in-the-terminal) here for more relevant issues.